# How do I determine my fuel level in Silent Hunter 5?

Tags: silent-hunter-5

The manual doesn't state where to find it. A web search says "the engineer can report it", but Joseph doesn't have this option in his dialog. I cannot determine which gauge on the boat show this information. Ditto on CO2, batteries, etc.

Can someone guide me please?

Comment: I added a new tag for Silent Hunter 5 and removed the one for control. Control is a super vague tag and I didn't see how it applied here.

Comment: I couldn't create new tags and couldn't find much better. Thank you @BrootsWaymb.